# How to properly check if a DNS entry exists using c#

Tags: c#, dns

I have a list of computers by name.  I'd like to see if the computers on the network are connected by using the `System.Net.Ping` and `System.Net.PingReply`.  The list of computers may become stale from time to time. If the host is not found I get an exception. Is there a way that I can check to see if there is a record of the host without experiencing an exception?  I thought I might be able to use `Dns.GetHostEntry(c.Name)` but this also returns an exception if the host is not in DNS.

Comment: Why not wrap `GetHostEntry` in a `try`/`catch` block?

Comment: I did but I thought there may be a way to check without generating an exception.

Comment: Not unless you reinvent the wheel, like construct the UDP request yourself, or call nslookup from your code, or find a web service that'll do DNS requests, which all sound unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're unable to use a try/catch, you could use [SimpleDNS](https://github.com/K1tson/SimpleDNS) (Nuget as well) which only throws exceptions on connection issues to the chosen DNS server.

```
var dnsServer = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");
var result = Query.Simple(new SimpleDnsPacket(new Question("lalalalalaldasl.com", QType.A), dnsServer)); //Failing Query
```

The return DNS packet object will be null if query was invalid:

[image]

and rather than checking for `null`, you could query the `Response` property found in the Header:

```
//Continued on from above....

if (result.Header.Parameters.Response != ResponseCode.Ok)
{
      //Something here!
}
```